# New Data frame showing nan values after concatenating main data frame with a dummy data frame in python

Tags: python, dataframe, nan

I am new to data science. I first created dummy data frame & I want to concatenate the dummy data frame to another data frame. Both data frames do not contain any nan values individually. But when I concatenate them , then nan values appear in the new data frame. The resulting Data frame is to be then fed to linear regression model, which is giving error owing to nun values

Image:

[image]

Comment: Put your code and part of the table here. Can't say anything without looking at them. It would be better if you can share csv / exel file via google drive or any

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.